# Converting a string value to an unkown (at compile time) object type

Tags: java, class

I have a class type and I have a value in a string:

```
Class<?> type = Integer.class // <-- in reality, that type is 
                              // determined at runtime
String value = "3";           // <-- same here, actually read from a file
```

My goal is to instantiate an instance of 'type' and fill it with the value of 'value'... So that I have the equivalent of

```
Integer i = new Integer(value);
```

Is the only possible way to do that a long chain of if-statements:

```
if (type == Integer.class) {
  // do this
}
```

Or is there another clever/right way to do that? The possible class types could be totally different like Integer/Date etc...

**Edit1**

Here some more context:

I have a file with a number of values which a textual representations of instances of different datatypes:

```
1|3.4|2011-08-24
```

In my program, I get a class type and a method in that class which are both unknown to me at compile time.

I want to call that method on an instance of that type, with the values from the file as parameters. But for that I do have to have the corresponding object to that values, in the example that could be an Integer/int, a float/double, a Date.
I can get these datatypes for the formal parameters of the method via reflection, but I'm uncertain about the best way to proceed with the conversion from string to the object...

Maybe this pseudo program will clear things up:

```
String[] values = getValuesFromFile;
Class<?> type = getType();
Method method = getMethod();
Class<?>[] formalParameterTypes = getMethodParameterTypes();
Object[] objects;
for(int i; i < values.length; i++)
  objects[i] = convert(values[i],formalParameterTypes[i]);
method.invoke(objects);
```

Comment: please show more context around the usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my understanding, you want something like this:

```
Object instance = createMagically(getClass(), getString());
```

where `getClass()` might return `Integer.class` and `getString()` the value `"42"`. But the value pair `Date.class` and `"15 Apr 2011"` is expected too.

At one point you'll have to work with conditions (if/else if) because, in general, every type has it's own conversion rules. There is no universal constructor to create an instance from a String.

So you *could* implement a "factory" method like this:

```
public static Object createInstance(Class<?> type, String content) {
  if (type.equals(Integer.class)) return new Integer(content);
  else if // ...
  return content;  // just an idea for a default if the type can't be handled
}
```

And then again, to *use* the return value, you may need some more if/else if to determine the actual type (`if (value instancof Integer)` ...)

So, from my point of view - you *have* to do a lot of checks, but you can hide the ugly magic in utility classes.

Comment: Yes, that's the way I wanted to do it... I just thought there could be a better way I didn't know about...

Answer (score 2):

Dynamic class loading and reflection were invented to solve such problems. E.g.

```
Class<?> type = Class.forName("MyClassName");
Object obj = type.newInstance();
```

Now if you want to set fields in the object, you have two options:

- if the potential classes share a common base class/interface, you can cast the object down to that interface and manipulate it via the interface methods,
- if the potential classes aren't related by inheritance but have the same method/field, you can set the field value through [bean introspection](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/javabeans/introspection/index.html), or you can call the method using reflection.

Comment: And what happens if you try `Integer.class.newInstance()`?

Comment: @jarnbjo, you will get an exception of course. The above is an example to point towards the right direction, not production code.

Comment: @jarnbjo - that would require that that the class is known at compile time. But in fact it isn't.

Answer (score 1):

If your type is limited to the wrapper classes for the primitive data types, all classes have a static valueOf(String) method, which can be used to parse a String and return a valid instance.

I would use reflection to find and invoke the method and use the result:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    int i = parse(Integer.class, "4711");
    double d = parse(Double.class, "47.11");
    boolean b = parse(Boolean.class, "true");
    System.out.println(i);
    System.out.println(d);
    System.out.println(b);
}

public static <T> T parse(Class<T> type, String value) {
    try {
        return (T)type.getDeclaredMethod("valueOf", String.class).invoke(null, value);
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: The type isn't limited to wrappers, he mentioned `Date` already.

Answer (score 0):

Using JSON you can convert string to object at runtime, without knowing the original type at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

If values have only string representations, you would to do so:

```
String typeName = ...
String value = ...
Class<?> type = Class.forName(typeName);
Constructor<?> constructor = type.getConstructor(String.class);
Object instance = constructor.newInstance(value);
// cast the instance to actual class
```